# How to enable CORS on Google App Engine Python Server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cors

I am see the following error on Javascript console:

```
VM31:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load '<some-url>'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<my-url>' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How do I enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing with Google App Engine (Python) to access ?

Comment: Is <some-url> a static file, or something you're handling with python code? Jeffery's answer covers the first case...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to use the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` http header in your yaml configuration

```
handlers:
- url: /
  ...
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://my-url
```

Find more under CORS Support in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig)

Comment: How about doing it for the whole app? what should be provided under static_dir

Comment: @JeffreyGodwyll I am getting the same issue. I am trying to add the http_header for a script and getting an error: google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unexpected attribute "http_headers" for mapping type script.

Comment: This property (`http_headers`) is intentionally disallowed for script handlers. Here's a workaround for PHP: https://github.com/riannucci/rietveldv2/issues/27

Answer (score 11):

For a python script you can add the following line near other self.response.header lines.

```
self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

This worked for me.  The idea was taken from a php issue listed in the notes of another answer.

Comment: also `response = flask.jsonify({'status': 'UP!'})
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')`

Answer (score 1):

For those who are wondering how to basically allow all origins for the AppEngine instance in Springboot:

- use the `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` annotation on the `@RestController` classes your project has
- or use use the same annotation above for any of your specific resource methods that has one of the `@GetMapping, @PostMapping, etc` annotations.

**No need to set any of the handlers in the app.yaml. Actually it didn't work when changing the app.yaml file as explained in the docs**

```java
...
...
...

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")  // <--- here 
public class SpringbootApplication {

 ...
 ...
  @GetMapping("/")      
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*").     // <--- or here 
  public String hello() {
      .....
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve a script, you cannot use Jeffrey Godwyll's answer, unfortunately. The documentation, somewhat [hidden](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_element) in the second sentence of the `http_headers` states: "If you need to set HTTP headers in your script handlers, you should instead do that in your app's code."

Another possibility is to allow your app to handle pre-flight requests by "prematurely" returning the headers. GOTCHA: If you are building a POST endpoint, make it so that it returns the allow cross site origin request headers on everything BUT your desired request method. Sometimes there may be a pre-flight GET as well (for some odd reason):

```py
from flask import Flask, request

HEADERS = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
}

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():
    if request.method != "POST":
        return ("", 204, HEADERS)

    return "After the POST"
```

If you are building an app for GET only, you can instead write `if request.method == "OPTIONS":...`, like in the [Cloud Functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#preflight_request)