# Cloud Endpoints Handler SSL redirect blocked by CORS

Tags: google-app-engine, cors, google-cloud-endpoints

I would like my Cloud Endpoints API to be called with HTTPS. My `app.yaml` file contains the following:

```
# The endpoints handler must be mapped to /_ah/api.
- url: /_ah/api/.*
  script: main.api
  secure: always
```

If a client (i.e. website) makes an insecure (HTTP) call to the endpoint URL, App Engine performs a redirect to the secure version (HTTPS)

For example, suppose my App Engine app is at `http://api.endpoints.my-app.appspot.com` and the API endpoint for making a HTTP GET request to the method `mymethod` is:

```
http://api.endpoints.my-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/myapp/v1/mymethod
```

App Engine redirects to the HTTP**S** version:

```
https://api.endpoints.my-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/myapp/v1/mymethod
```

However, the redirect from is blocked:

`blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

How can I add the required header to my resource (i.e. my Cloud Endpoints API on App Engine)? Google's documentation states CORS is enabled by default on App Engine Standard - which is what I'm using. So I'm unsure why this is even a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to configure the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in `app.yml`. For your case, please try the following to the `app.yml` file:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/api/.*
  script: main.api
  secure: always
  http_headers:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4000
```

More to read:

- [`app.yml` reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref)
- [A related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31212992/how-to-enable-cors-on-google-app-engine-python-server)